# when writing to csv file writerow fails with UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, csv, exception

I have the line:

```
c.writerow(new_values)
```

That writes a number of values to a csv file. Normally it is working fine but sometimes it throws an exception and doesn't write the line in the csv file. I have no idea how I can find out why.

This is my exception handling right now:

```
        try:
            c.writerow(new_values)
        except:
            print()
            print ("Write Error: ", new_values)
```

I commented out my own exception and it says:

```
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b1' in position 14: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: `it throws an exception` What exception is raised?

Comment: I see no exception. I see that you're excepting *any* exception. Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: Bare `except` is very bad practice. *"I have no idea how I can find out why."* - remove the `try: except:` and **read the error message**?

Comment: Ah, much better. You're trying to write a `α` and it can't be encoded.

Comment: How can I fix the "α" problem?

Answer (score 33):

Ok, I solved it by myself:

I just had to add ", encoding='utf-8'" to my csv.writer line:

```
c = csv.writer(open("Myfile.csv", 'w',  newline='', encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: Works in Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

the csv module in python is notorious for not handling unicode characters well.  Unless all characters fall in the ascii codec you probably won't be able to write the row.  There is a (somewhat) drop in replacement called unicodecsv that you may want to look into.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv

Comment: So it is not possible to write a "α"/Alpha letter to a csv file with python?

Comment: OP is using Python 3 (inferred from use of the print function).  There is no issue using unicode with Python 3 csv.

Comment: I would disagree that this must be python 3.  Those print functions work perfectly well in python 2--they just add parens.

Comment: How can I modify it or add something to make it work?

Comment: @bgm387:  That's why I said it was inferred.  `print()` in Python 2 will print an empty tuple unless the OP is using `from __future__ import print_function`.  We can also infer that it is Python 3 because of the answer the OP just posted.